# Upload image to AWS s3 storage from Laravel showed Heroku Server 500 Error

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, heroku

I've added

> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
> AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
> AWS_BUCKET

in Heroku
and the according value to Heroku Config Vars.

Then, I uploaded image to '/images' folder on s3.

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('/images', 's3');
```

After that, Heroku server showed the following error：

[server error 500 title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoLQZ.png)
[server error 500 specific](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnJ5t.png)

Is there anyone can help me explain what's going on? Thanks a lots. I'm trying figure out...

**UPDATE：**

Here is my create.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
        <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I took @Rwd's advice, type `dd($request->hasFile('image'));` in controller

 In localhost, it showed `true`

 In Heroku Server, it showed `false`

**SOLUTION**

@bhucho adviced to change `form action` from `"/"` to `" {{url('/') }} "`

And it returned `true` now, I can upload image to s3.

Thanks everyone's help！

Comment: have you tried using `Storage::disk('s3')->put('/images', $request->file('image'));` or even `$path = Storage::disk('s3')->putFile('images', $request->file('image'));`

Comment: @bhucho thanks for your suggestion, it turned out to be  something looks like this `FilesystemAdapter->put()` and the second way resulted in `FilesystemAdapter->putFile()` Both of them is `The "" file does not exist or is not readable.`

Comment: Can you confirm the request definitely has a file i.e. what do you get if you do `dd($request->hasFile('image'));` above `$path = $req...`?

Comment: @Rwd hi, it showed "false" in Heroku Server, but it showed "true" in Localhost. thanks for your answer. Here is my input looks like `<input type="file" name="image" id="image">`

Comment: I believe this `form action="/"` will not work for your server, use `form action=" {{url('/') }} " `, also check that you have added the url in your `APP_URL` .env file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `<form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` to `<form action="{{ url('/') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

In the development server environment, it will run fine.See Mozilla Docs for [The action attribute of form tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_action_attribute)

However, deploying it to anywhere else but the root website will cause the action URL to become invalid. For instance, if it were deployed to https://example.com/deployed_app, then the actual action URL that the form will call is https://example.com/Home/Upload, which is invalid.

So if you use `{{ url() }}` it will append the url mentioned in APP_URL of .env file.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried to use `action="{{ route('image.upload') }}"` and in the routes, I give the route name `->name('image.upload');`  and it worked too.